# css image with background image

Tags: css, image, background

Just wondering if this is possible using css

I want to emulate a 40x40 table with a background image (that size already) and another image (also 40x40) sitting on top of that.

I know background image is possible but not sure if the image that sits on top is?

Comment: To clarify, you want to know if it is possible to stack two background images on top of each other in CSS? (if that is the question, the quick answer is yes)

Answer (score 0):

can you nest an `img` inside a `div`?

```
    <div style="width: 40px; height: 40px; background-image: url(under.jpg);">
            <img style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="on-top.jpg" />
    </div>
```